# How to call a function with a parameter in ExtJs Row Expander Body?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem using the Row Expander plugin in ExtJs. What I'm trying to do is call the formatThrottle function and pass the throttleState along with it.

This is one of those silly syntax things, you can see what I'm trying to do but I get a syntax error on the second round bracket, the other lines work perfect and are already in our codebase - hence my next question as I didn't originally develop this:

What is the mechanism called where a parameter value from the current row can be passed to HTML using {}(curly brackets)? Is this a row expander thing or a general JavaScript thing?

### EDIT: Fiddle link with the fix for my issue:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lbn

---

```
rowBodyTpl :
'<table><tr>' +
    '<td class="TdIndent"/>' +
    '<td class="TdItemsWidth">' + formatThrottle( + '{throttleState}' + ) + '</td>' +
    '<td class="TdAmountWidth">{throttleReason}</td>' +
    '<td class="TdIndent"/>' +
    '<td class="TdItemsWidth">{throttleState}</td>' +
    '<td class="TdAmountWidth">{throttleReason}</td>' +
'</tr></table>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
rowBodyTpl: [
     '<table><tr><td>{[this.formatThrottleState(values.id)]}</td></tr></table>', {
            formatThrottleState : function(throttleState) {
               if(throttleState === 1) {
                 return "formatted";
               } else {
                  return "not formattted";
               }
            }
        }
]
```

Hopefully that will help you out.

The function must be passed as part of the template so that it remains within scope.

You might also find something useful in the documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

As you have it now it is trying to call formatThrottle immediately and the syntax is incorrect. You will want it to run after the actual values have been populated.

The curly brackets will just be replaced using logic within the row expander class.

Comment: You're correct I need to get the script to run after the values are populated. Except the script tag doesn't seem to run - I tested with alert messages and "window.log()" messages and it is not executing. Any ideas why it isn't running?

Comment: After some trial and error and a bit of RTFM I've updated my answer which should do what you require.

Comment: You're an absolute gent! That fixed my issue! I should have RTFM myself but I'm quite new to Javascript so certain syntax things like this are lost on me!